# cgroup memory usage is different from sum of memory usage of sub cgroups

Tags: linux, docker, cgroups, container

The memory usage I see here:

```
sudo cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes
```

is different the from the sum of memory usage of the sub cgroups, which I calculated by getting all the sub cgroups using the following command:

```
sudo ls -dltrh /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/*/
```

Then I took the sum of the `memory.usage_in_bytes` for all of these sub cgroups. From what I understand, these two values should match.

Comment: Related: [Cgroup memory.usage_in_bytes shows incorrect value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451252/cgroup-memory-usage-in-bytes-shows-incorrect-value). No upvoted/accepted answer for this question, but it has some useful discussion.